# Multiple basename() extensions

Tags: php

We have:

```
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "index"
$file = 'index';                 // the result
```

How can we query a multiple file extensions? Instead of

```
$file = basename($path, ".php");
```

something like

```
$file = basename($path, ".php,gif,png,jpeg,css,js,html");
```

So, If `$path = "/home/image.png";` `$file` will get value 'image'.

I've tryed to use `pathinfo()` and `[filename]`, but my server doesn't support PHP 5.2.

Comment: there are many solutions. tell us for what particular task you need that,  and get most proper solution

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel just need to get the filename without extension.

Comment: again. there are A LOT of tasks that require that. FOR EXAMPLE, doing that pathinfo()+in_array() way would be stupid if you need glob(). For what you need that?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I will push the value of this string to array() and then echo somewhere

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php#89127

Comment: You can use this function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: What's the problem with size? Those are functions. Put them into separate file and include when you need.

Comment: Ignat, that's not an answer. You are answering me as though I am gestapo officer questioning you. Telling the whole story will help you, not me. Though it's up to you, to continue wrong way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$file = basename($path);
$info = pathinfo($file);
$name = basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']); // index
```

if you using PHP > 5.2.0

```
$info = pathinfo('/www/awesomepath/index.php');
$name = $info['filename']; //index
```

Comment: damn, this is a logical solution. I'm newbie at programming, sometimes I feel like a donkey.

Comment: If you already use pathino() why do you also need basename()? `echo pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do

```
preg_match('/[\/]*([^\/]+)\.([^\.]+)$/i', $file, $match);
//$match[1] -> the result
//$match[2] -> the extension
```

Comment: Works, but its too interesting, is it possible to use basename() with multiple extensions?